# How do I fill in a 2D array in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, 2d

This is my code:

```
empty = ' '
board = [[empty, empty, empty], [empty, empty, empty], [empty, empty, empty]]

def print_board():
    for idx, val in enumerate(board):
        print(val)

def board_update(x,y,player):
    board[x:y] = player;

game_is_running = True
player = 'x'
print_board()



while game_is_running:
    if player == 'x':
        print ('x turn')
        ver = int(input('input vertical of x '))
        hor = int(input('input horizontal of x '))
        board_update(ver, hor, player)
        player = 'o'
    print_board()

    if player == 'o':
        print ('o')
        vertical = int(input('input vertical of o '))
        horizontal = int(input('input horizontal of o '))
```

Whenever I run the code, it just places the letter like this:

```
[' ', ' ', ' ']

x

[' ', ' ', ' ']

[' ', ' ', ' ']
```

How do I make it look like this:

```
[' ', ' ', ' ']

[' ', x ,  ' ']

[' ', ' ', ' ']
```

Comment: `board[x:y] = player` doesn't do what you think it does. You want `board[x][y] = player`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is in line

```
board[x:y] = player;
```

the `[x:y]` notation is for assigning ranges while what you really need is probably

```
board[x][y] = player
```

Normally you would get an error because assigning single value to a range will throw `TypeError`. In this case you are assigning string which python treats as a list of characters let's say.

Answer (score 0):

`board[x:y]` is slicing syntax. In your case, you seem to have tried `board[1:1] = "x"`. Let's see what that does:

`board[1:1]` refers to the part of the list from index 1 to index 1 (an empty part, but a part nonetheless):

```
  ['','',''], ['','',''], ['','','']
0            1           2          3
             ⇈
```

Since you set that slice to `"x"` (and a string is a sequence), the list now becomes:

```
  ['','',''], 'x', ['','',''], ['','','']
0            1    2           3          4
```

What you want to do instead is access the second list inside the list (`board[1]`), and the 1st element of that inner list (`board[1][1]`):

```
board[x:y] = player
```